# QR code output error in php

Tags: php

I have written a code to  get a barcode when i am trying to get the output it comes as the given image [this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIHGS.png)

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart? 
chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&choe=UTF-8");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send PNG header before send any char to browser:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

and if you want to force download image use this code:

```
header('Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=imagename.png');
header('Content-type: image/png');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion but when i use this header('Content-Type: image/png'); it does shows me the black screen but the barcode is not coming. Anything else that i need to add?

Answer (score 0):

Check header type:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: image/jpeg"));
```

Comment: the QR is png not jpg

Comment: change content type accordingly! @Mahdi Parsa Sir.